# Is it possible to connect to multiple mobile devices non-wireless and run tests

Tags: usb

[image]Is it possible to connect from computer to multiple mobile devices via USB and run tests on mobile devices while they (devices) are connected to Wireless network of another device.?

Scenario: We have some proprietary devices that have their own WiFi radio signal. We need to connect mobile devices to that signal. Then, we need to connect to that mobile device at the same time and inject tests. I've added a diagram to explain our need. Is it possible?

Any help/ pointers would be appreciated!!

Comment: This question made my head go all funny - it isn't very clear what exactly your setup is (not to me anyway). I think maybe reword or add some kind of viual aid to help others understand what you're asking.

Comment: Why not? All `adb` commands can be executed with multiple devices connected, you just have to tell it which device is the target.

Comment: *how can we connect to mobile devices from our PCs*  well I really don't get what this meant. But you said you can connect to WiFi right? And then what's you problem?

Comment: Firstly sorry for unclear description.

Comment: Firstly sorry for unclear description. The scenario is to test an app's features on mobile device which would be connected to an electronic board's own wifi signal. While the mobile device is connected to the board, we need to connect to it and pass on test commands. We need to do this for multiple mobile devices. So, we are researching on any solutions that could enable creating such device farm where we could pass instructions to mobile devices while they are connected wirelessly to electronic boards. Sorry, if it is not clear. I'll add some diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible . 
If your devices are android you can simply use scripts including adb commands

Steps :

1. GEt Device ID : 
   adb devices
2. Pass adb command :
   adb -s $device_id shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS

Sample Script :
You can take device id as command line parameter

```
      for($i=1; $i<=$temp;$i++)
      {
      print "\n********* Opening activities : **********\n";
      system("adb -s $devices shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS");
      sleep 5;
      system("adb -s $devices shell input tap 200 200");
      sleep 25;
      }
```